# The image of a bounded set by a linear function is bounded iff the function is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(A, d_a)$ and $(B, d_b)$ be two metric space such that:

-$A$ is bounded set of real valued functions, $d_a$ is the metric corresponding to the sup norm.

-$B$ is a set of real valued functions.

We have $\mu: A \to B$ a linear application, think of an integral for example.

Is it true that $\mu(A$) is bounded $\iff \mu $ is continuous ?

Comment: There certainly are discontinuous linear functions that send *some* bounded subsets to bounded sets (namely, to $\{0\}$).

Comment: What is the metric on $B$?